# Advanced if statements

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm trying to incorporate multiple if statements, where only 1 if statement is executed. But I need to be able to see which parameter(if) it took. So I can better enhance it.

Currently it executes all if statements that matches if they are true.
I want it to only execute one.

This is my code:

```
c=2
d=15
body=30

if (( c >= 0 && c<= 3 && d >= 13 && d <= 30 && body >= 13 && body <= 30)); then
 bash -c "echo 'Parameter 1 were taken'"
 fi;

if (( c >= 0 && c<= 3 && d >= 5 && d <= 7 && body >= 18 && body <= 24)); then
 bash -c "echo 'Parameter 2 were taken'"
 fi;

if (( c >= 0 && c<= 6 && d >= 4 && d <= 6 && body >= 25 && body <= 30)); then
 bash -c "echo 'Parameter 3 were taken'"
 fi;
```

Based on this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/bash/comments/xw6z11/advanced_if_statements/) I've read that you should use `|| \`

How could I check all above if statements and only execute ONE if parameter matches the values?

Comment: `if cmd1; then ...; elif cmd2; then ... ; elif cmd3; then ...; else cmd4; fi`

Comment: I think you mean "branch" rather than "parameter".

Comment: Why are you doing `bash -c "echo...` instead of just `echo ...`?

Comment: Search the bash man page for `elif`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
a=2
b=15
c=30

ranges=(
    # a  |  b   |  c   |         info         |
    '0 3  13 30  13 30  Parameter 1 were taken'
    '0 3  5  7   18 24  Parameter 2 were taken'
    '0 6  4  6   25 30  Parameter 3 were taken'
)

for item in "${ranges[@]}"; {
    read   a1         a2         b1         b2         c1         c2             info <<< $item
    ((a >= a1 && a <= a2 && b >= b1 && b <= b2 && c >= c1 && c <= c2)) && echo "$info"
}
Parameter 1 were taken
```